# Beginners Visual Basic Help: I am to create a simple "game" which prompts a user to enter a number 1-10. That number must be stored

Tags: visual-studio, loops, numbers

Beginners Visual Basic Help: I am to create a simple "game" which prompts a user to enter a number 1-10. That number must be stored. Then the real game begins, Using a loop have the user try to guess the number stored. Notify if the guess is too high, too low, or correct. Continue loop until correct.

I am very stuck right now; all I have is-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mynumber, input As Integer
        mynumber = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        input = TextBox1.Text
```

Please Help I Know this is very simple but this class is very complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, to start off I'm going to use your variables and we're going to declare these so the whole of the form can access them.

```
Dim mynumber As Integer
Dim input As Integer
```

We're also going to declare a seperate variable which will count the amount of times that the user has tried to guess the number, and also the number that they are going to be guessing which in this case is declared as `guessnumber`

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim guessnumber As Integer
```

You want to create a button and call it `btnNewGame` which will start the game playing and this is going to be the code that you'll add to that button:

```
Dim mynumber As Random
guessnumber = Number.Next(10) + 1
```

This will create the random number and have it change to a new value when the new game button is clicked, so no game is the same.

We want to initialize the counter now so that whenever a new game is started then the amount of guesses that the user has had is 0 and we also want to initialize the textbox so that it is empty when the new game button is clicked.

```
counter = 0
txtInput.Text = ""
```

So now, underneath a separate play button we want to add this code

```
Dim uni As Integer
uni = CInt(txtInput.Text)
counter = counter + 1
```

Now lets add in a 'Try' function which will run through until the user has either guessed the number or exceeded the amount of turns which is 3. You can easily alter the amount of turns.

```
    Try
            If uni = guessnumber Then
                MessageBox.Show("You guessed my Number!")
            ElseIf uni < guessnumber Then
                MessageBox.Show("Your guess is too low")
            ElseIf uni > guessnumber Then
       MessageBox.Show("Your guess is too high.")
       End If
 Catch E1 As InvalidCastException
MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number and try again.")
  End Try
```

Hope this helps you, please let me know how you get on!